# Abstraction of a pattern noticed involving BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am noticing a pattern like below in few of my classes. 
How can I abstract that away? Any suggestions?

```
private void InitializeClass()
{
    BackgroundWorker bgw1 = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgw1.DoWork += (s,e) =>
    {
        // doing work
    };

    BackgroundWorker bgw2 = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgw2.DoWork += (s,e) =>
    {
        // doing work
    };

    BackgroundWorker bgw3 = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgw3.DoWork += (s,e) =>
    {
        // doing work
    };

    bgw1.RunWorkerAsync();
    bgw2.RunWorkerAsync();
    bgw3.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: The workers don't depend on each other and you don't want to wait for any results?

Comment: @VVS: Good point. However, it does seem that the workers are not dependent on each others from what I have noticed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static class Worker
{
    public static void Execute(params DoWorkEventHandler[] handlers)
    {
        foreach (DoWorkEventHandler handler in handlers)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            DoWorkEventHandler capturedHandler = handler;

            worker.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    capturedHandler(sender, e);
                }
                finally
                {
                    worker.Dispose();    
                }
            };

            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
Worker.Execute((s, e) =>
{
    // doing work
});
```

or if you wanted to schedule multiple events:

```
Worker.Execute(
    (s, e) => 
    {
        // doing work
    },
    (s, e) => 
    {
        // doing work
    },
    (s, e) => 
    {
        // doing work
    }
);
```

---

UPDATE:

Here's an alternative which allows you to specify a completed handler:

```
public class Worker
{
    public Worker Work(DoWorkEventHandler doWork, RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler complete)
    {
        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += doWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += complete; 
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        return this;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
new Worker()
    .Work((s, e) => { /** some work **/ }, (s, e) => { /** work completed **/ })
    .Work((s, e) => { /** some work **/ }, (s, e) => { /** work completed **/ })
    .Work((s, e) => { /** some work **/ }, (s, e) => { /** work completed **/ });
```

Comment: To avoid loosing the ref to the worker, it could accept an instance of a bgworker as a parameter, or return the created instance. More often than not you will need access to it for other events, disposing it, allowing progress report and cancellation. But i like the general pattern

Comment: @havardhu, the whole idea here is to abstract the background worker. So we don't need a ref to it. If we needed to perform some task when the function completes we could pass an additional argument to the Execute method.

Comment: Hmm I like that idea. Out of interest, how would you handle Dispose on the worker?

Comment: Hope you don't mind, added code to dispose of worker. (@havardhu see update)

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: This is awesome! Just to make it interesting - I also noticed that "some" BGWorkers had a `bg2.Completed += ...` handlers as well, how would you suggest to take that into account? What's a good way to extend this solution.

Comment: @chibacity that's interesting as well. however, wouldn't this cause the Dispose to occur before the RunWorkerCompleted event is fired?

Comment: @havardhu No I have wrapped the handler, so the handler will be called  before Dispose is called on the worker.

Comment: @Chibacity @havardhu: In my solution, I am making use of the using statement - `using (var bgw = new BackgroundWorker()) { //DoWork & RunWorkerCompleted }` This way you won't need to explicitly call the Dispose on the BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @Voodoo I'm not sure of the exact implications, but you should not dispose of the worker with a using as this could result in the worker being disposed before your job has finished - it is asynchronous. I have disposed of it explicitly so that the async job is guaranteed to be finished. You should dispose on the worker thread, not the thread the worker is created on.

Comment: @chibacity: Interesting, I will have to do more research on it now to be sure. Would disposing BGW in `finally` block of the `DoWork` handler have any effect on `RunWorkerCompleted` handler? I would assume that this event would still be raised, could you share your thoughts? I see you mentioned that the handler will be called before dispose, so does that mean its handlers' job to raise the RunWorkerCompleted?

Comment: @chibacity I did a quick test on your solution and it worked like a charm. I don't understand why, though, since I assumed he 'wrapping' lambda would be the worker's DoWorkEventHandler and the wrapped handler would just be any old delegate. The event fires, though; can you enlighten me as to why? :)

Answer (score 1):

May be you can do something like this. A *pseudocode*:

```
public abstract class BaseClass 
{
     public abstract DoWork1();
     public abstract DoWork2();
     public abstract DoWork3();


     protected void InitializeClass()
     {
        BackgroundWorker bgw1 = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw1.DoWork += (s,e) =>
        {
           DoWork1();
        };

        BackgroundWorker bgw2 = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw2.DoWork += (s,e) =>
        {
           DoWork2();
        };

        BackgroundWorker bgw3 = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw3.DoWork += (s,e) =>
        {
           DoWork3();
        };

        bgw1.RunWorkerAsync();
        bgw2.RunWorkerAsync();
        bgw3.RunWorkerAsync();
    }


}
```

after this in any derived class, something like this:

```
public class DerivedClass: BaseClass 
{
    public override DoWork1(){}  //DoWork1 concrete implementaiton

    public override DoWork2(){}  //DoWork2 concrete implementaiton

    public override DoWork3(){}  //DoWork3 concrete implementaiton

}
```

So when you call `InitializeClass()` method, you call base class method which will  invoke overrides of concrete class.

Remark: If the number of background workers can vary, you can merge a solution of Darin with this one (in other words have a collection of invokers).

Hope this helps.